# Save data from modal (popup form) into local database - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I manage to implement insert function successfully as below. But this one is done by using another view -"Create", Once submit it goes to "ViewSecurityForm" View. But now, I want to implement the insert function using modal in "ViewSecurityForm". I have few modals to be implemented in "ViewSecurityForm" view. Can you help me how to do it?

**My method for create function in "Create" view:**

```
   public ActionResult Create(ServerInfo alldata)
    {
        try
        {

            db.ServerInfos.Add(alldata);
            db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Employee", action = "ViewSecurityForm" });
        }
        catch

        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**My method for modal in "ViewSecurityForm" view:**

```
public ActionResult ViewSecurityForm()
{


/*What should I write here*/      


}
```

**My class:**

```
public class ViewSecurityForm
{
    public List<ServerInfo> allServerInfo { get; set; }
    public List<NetworkDeviceInfo> allNetworkDeviceInfo { get; set; }

}


public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
    //Create database without name 
    public SecurityContext ()
    {       

        Database.SetInitializer(new SecurityDBInitializer());
    }

    //Create Table as below            
    public DbSet<ServerInfo> ServerInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NetworkDeviceInfo> NetworkDeviceInfos { get; set; }


}
```

[My Modal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3oR8.png)

Comment: show your form code.